# Can the micro USB port be used for data?

Tags: usb

To my current knowledge the micro USB port on the raspberry pi is used solely for power supply.

But is is possible to also use this port for data? Is there a way to activate this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you transfer data through the microUSB?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/can-you-transfer-data-through-the-microusb)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No - the data lines are not connected.