# Connecting Android Tablet And RPI Using USB Cable

Tags: usb, android

I have an Android application that can communicate with a device connected to OTG port in the android tab (via direct USB connection).  It works fine. Now I want the Raspberry Pi to act as a repeater(just forward data coming from USB connection with tablet to another USB device or the other way around). My Android app is programmed to make the tablet work as the host. Is there any method to make this work using only two USB cables between the tablet and the rPi and between the rPi and the USB device?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Exchange! Have you written this Android application yourself? If yes, the most likely route to follow is to write your own rPi application (in Python, C, C++, Java, whatever language you are most familiar with) to do exactly what the Android app already does regarding receiving and sending USB messages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Android app is not written by me. I have written an application using serialPi(available on wiringPi) in C++ for the Pi.  when I connect the tab to Raspberry pi it detect the tab and create a file ttyACM0 in /etc/dev. Using this file I tried to communicate with tab but tab doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

> My Android app is programmed to make the tablet work as the host.

In this case the answer is no; the micro USB connector [is power only](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8590/5538) (no data) and the other USB jacks [work in host mode only](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22515/5538).