# Does RPi4 support video IN (usb c)

Tags: hdmi, usb-c

This could probably be more of a generic hardware question but I plan to use an RPi 4.

Does the RPi 4 with usb C have the possibility of receiving HDMI input.

So essentially I want to use the RPi 4 as a capture card without any additional hardware.

Is this IN THEORY possible?

Comment: i could be wrong, but it appears that RPi4 has no HDMI input capability

Answer (score 4):

The Pi4 DOES NOT HAVE a USB-C port.

It uses a USB-C connector for power.

In contrast to earlier Pi models the power power port does have data lines but only USB2 OTG is supported.

Comment: https://hitaltech.co.uk/raspberry-pi-4-gets-its-usb-c-port-fixed-allowing-high-speed-usb-3-1-cables/

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=243966

Comment: So the second link mainly suggests data transfer is very much possible

Comment: Could please clarify about earlier Pi models microUSB port having data capabilities? [This question and answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/can-you-transfer-data-through-the-microusb) seems to suggest the opposite for the very early versions of Pis.